# Find out which hardware is causing system interrupts intermittently on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop-computer, interrupts

Lately, my desktop computer has been getting unusual "System Interrupts" intermittently on Windows 10 which slows down my PC a lot. It lasts for a few seconds to half a minute. It happens about once a day.

I suspect it's some hardware problem but I can use my PC without any problem now. How do I troubleshoot which hardware is failing, assuming this is indeed the case?

My motherboard is B450 Aorus Pro Wifi.

Comment: Best I could do to diagnose system interrupts>>>>https://web.archive.org/web/20100406100838/http://www.msfn.org/board/cause-high-usage-interrupt-t140263.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History and see if it has reported hardware errors. If you have such errors, they will show up here.

You can click on a Red dot to expand the error and find the errant driver. Of course this will be for your machine, but I am offering method and example here.

[image]

Comment: Run `perfmon.exe /rel`

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question since it is specific to my PC. I got the answer thanks to comment from @John. Credit is not mine.

I looked in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Reliability History. From there, I saw the culprint. It was `Radeon Settings`. Radeon software is unnecessary since I'm using Nvidia GPU on my PC.

Lesson to learn from my bad interrupts experience is not to install AMD Radeon software when one is already using Nvidia GPU.

I have uninstalled AMD software. No problem so far.

EDIT: The same problem happened again despite me uninstalling AMD software. The question was answered because the fault was found. But ultimate solution remains elusive :(